# Tumblr OAuth using PHP's OAuth class

Tags: php, oauth, tumblr

Allright, I'm stumped on this one.

I recently downloaded and installed php's OAuth library here: https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.oauth.php

Using this, I created some test code to try to connect to my Tumblr account and make a post.

I am able to get the RequestToken and Authorize.  But when I make an actual request I get an error:

```
Invalid auth/bad request (got a 404, expected HTTP/1.1 20X or a redirect)
```

My request url is in the correct format of http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/account/post.  And I'm making a POST request.  So I am not sure why it's returning a 404.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$req_url = 'http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token';
$authurl = 'http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/authorize';
$acc_url = 'http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token';

$conskey = '123';
$conssec = '456';

session_start();

// In state=1 the next request should include an oauth_token.
// If it doesn't go back to 0
if(!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && $_SESSION['state']==1) $_SESSION['state'] = 0;
try {
  $oauth = new OAuth($conskey,$conssec);
  $oauth->enableDebug();
  if(!isset($_GET['oauth_token']) && !$_SESSION['state']) {
    $request_token_info = $oauth->getRequestToken($req_url, 'http://www.domain.com/oauth.php');
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $request_token_info['oauth_token_secret'];
    $_SESSION['state'] = 1;

    //Make authorize request with oauth_token
    header('Location: '.$authurl.'?oauth_token='.$request_token_info['oauth_token']);
    exit;
  } else if($_SESSION['state']==1) {
  
    //Callback code

    $oauth->setToken($_GET['oauth_token'],$_SESSION['secret']);
    $access_token_info = $oauth->getAccessToken($acc_url);
    $_SESSION['state'] = 2;
    $_SESSION['token'] = $access_token_info['oauth_token'];
    $_SESSION['secret'] = $access_token_info['oauth_token_secret'];

  } 

  //Make tumblr post request
  $oauth->setToken($_SESSION['token'],$_SESSION['secret']);
  $oauth->fetch("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/account/post", null, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, array('type'=>'text', 'body'=>'this is a test'));  //error happens here
  $json = json_decode($oauth->getLastResponse());
  print_r($json);
} catch(OAuthException $E) {
  print_r($E);
}
?>
```

Any hints are greatly appreciated

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the answer.

The problem lies here:

```
$oauth->fetch("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/account/post", null, OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST, array('type'=>'text', 'body'=>'this is a test'));  //error happens here
```

First of all, for account, I just had the name of my blog.  In fact, the base-hostname as described in the tumblr api needs to be in the format 'blogname.tumblr.com'.  Not just 'blogname' as I had it.  This will give a 400.

Secondly, the fetch parameters were in the wrong order.  The correct order is this:

```
string $protected_resource_url [, array $extra_parameters [, string $http_method [, array $http_headers ]]]
```

Which in translation to my example would be...

```
$oauth->fetch("http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/blogname.tumblr.com/post", array('type'=>'text', 'body'=>'this is a test'), OAUTH_HTTP_METHOD_POST );
```

I wrote a tutorial on getting this to work [here](http://vigrond.com/blog/2012/02/04/oauth-extension-php-and-the-tumblr-api/)

Comment: also don't forget to call setToken method before an authorized fetch call.